# Como escalar un polígono desde su centro

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Estoy creando un polígono en Windows Forms con C# a partir de un arreglo de puntos dentro de un elemento PictureBox y lo escalo con el método `ScaleTransform` de `PaintEventArgs.Graphics`

El problema es que cuando lo escalo el polígono se mueve de lugar y necesito que se escale desde su centro.

La variable scale es dinámica

```
Pen pen2 = new Pen(Color.Blue);
PointF[] curvePoints = lPoints.ToArray();
float scale = ((this.tb * 100) / this.w_origin) / 100;
e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(scale, scale);
e.Graphics.DrawPolygon(pen2, curvePoints);
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El escalado se hace desde (0,0). Para hacerlo desde el centro, primero tendrás que calcular cual es el centro. Después, aplica una transformación de traslación  para llevar el centro del polígono a (0,0)
Después se aplica el escalado, y de nuevo tienes que trasladar para
devolver el centro a su posición.

```
e.Graphics.TranslateTransform( -centro_x, -centro_y );
e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(scale, scale);
e.Graphics.TranslateTransform( centro_x, centro_y );
```

El cálculo del centro depende de los polígonos con los que trabajes. Puedes hacer la media de las coordenadas de todos los puntos por ejemplo.

Comment: Podrías dar un ejemplo sencillo por favor

Comment: Tu respuesta me ayudó a encontrar la solución, pero ahora quiero obtener las nuevas coordenadas del polígono.

Comment: Ya encontre la forma de encontrar las nuevas coordenadas con 'using (Matrix mat = e.Graphics.Transform){
                    mat.TransformPoints(curvePoints);
                    this.PointsPolygon = curvePoints;
                }'